# Consulta a servicio wsdl socket no permitido

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

Cuando llamo al servicio `wsdl` desde Python sobre SQL tengo el siguiente error:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
from suds.client import Client
url="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
'
```

Salida:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0 Error de script 'Python' durante la ejecución de 'sp_execute_external_script' con HRESULT 0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 Error en el script externo: 

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()

Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 Error en el script externo:    File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in connect
    super().connect()   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\http\client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa) OSError: [WinError 10013] Intento de acceso a un socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 5, in <module>   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\MSSQLSERVER01\90786657-B990-49F9-A9B9-AFDE8479659F\sqlindb.py", line 33, in transform
    client = Client(url)

Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 Error en el script externo:    File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 151, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py", line 135, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 78, in open
    d = self.download(url)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 94, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 174, in open
    return HttpTransport.open(self, request)

Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 Error en el script externo:    File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 63, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 119, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\urllib\request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\urllib\request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1256, in do_open

Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 Error en el script externo: 
    raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10013] Intento de acceso a un socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso>

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information. Mensaje(s) STDOUT del script externo:  SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 406, in rx_sql_satellite_call
    rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 291, in rx_native_call
    ret = px_call(functionname, params) RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.
```

Comment: Yo encontré una librería para python llamada zeep, es un poco compleja de entender al principio pero es lo que mejor funciona para python. te dejo el enlace [aquí](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/)

Comment: No creo sea un problema en la libreria ya que me sucede tambien con la libreria requests, igualmente voy a probar.

Answer (score 4):

Por suerte pude solucionar el inconveniente, el antivirus estaba bloqueando la conexion en este caso ESET EndPoint Antivirus.